# How to share a file from Google Drive with more than one user using Google Drive API for python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am able to share a file with a given user by:

```py
user_permission = ({
                    'type': 'user',
                    'role': 'writer',
                    'emailAddress': "example@gmail.com",
                   })
service.permissions().create(fileId=fileId,body=user_permission,fields='id').execute()
```

However, I don't know how to share the file with more than one user.

I have read the documentation in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create, and I understand that for more than user the value of the "type" key specified in the body must be "group" instead of "user", but I don't find anywhere how the format of the parameter "emailAddress" should be in this case. I have proved with a list of strings of mails, a string of mails separated by commas or by spaces, but this has given me the following error:

```py
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1shxOQlNPqbXT-LwKTDvuwK0m-7IK43cDAWwxmnLgLvQ/permissions?fields=id&emailMessage=This+is+a+test&alt=json returned "The specified emailAddress is invalid or not applicable for the given permission type.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'The specified emailAddress is invalid or not applicable for the given permission type.', 'locationType': 'other', 'location': 'permission.emailAddress'}]">
```

Comment: If you want to share with a group of users (this group of users not being a whole domain) you should [create a group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464926?hl=en) with all these users as members (here's how to [manage a group programmatically](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) and here how to [manage its members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members)). Then, the `emailAddress` would be the group email. If you don't do it this way, you'll have to give permissions individually to each user.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @lamblichus, I didn't know the concept of a Google Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Permission type `group` does not refer to any combination of different users. It refers to a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/).

#### Solution:

If you want to share a file with multiple users (these users not being a whole `domain`) you should [create a group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464926?hl=en) with all these users as members.

If you have a Workspace account, you can manage a group programmatically, using [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory) (see [Directory API: Groups](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) and [Directory API: Group Members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members)).

In this case, the `emailAddress` from the request body would the group email:

> if `type` is `user` or `group`, you must provide an `emailAddress` for the user or group

Otherwise, the only option is to share the file individually with the different users, as you are currently doing.

#### Reference:

- [Permission type](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create#type)